# HTML/CSS misplaced header and missing images

Tags: html, css, image, header

I am having a little issue with a few headers being misplaced on the site I am working on and also an image that's supposed to show below each one of them is not showing. 
You can see what I am talking about here:

[image: "To join" is supposed to be below the last images]

Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- main-content -->
<div id="main-content">    
    <h1> Check out all our DEADicated sites: </h1>
    <div class="sites">
        <a href="http://www.thedeadicated.tumblr.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/sites/tumblr.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Tumblr"/></a>
        <p> Tumblr </p>
    </div>
    <div class="sites">
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/thedeadicated" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/sites/twitter.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Twitter"/></a>
        <p> Twitter </p>
    </div>
    <div class="sites">     
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/DeadicatedRepository" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/sites/youtube.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="YouTube"/></a>
        <p> YouTube </p>
     </div>

    <h2> To join TheDEADicated, click <a href="http://musichype.com/artists/dead-sara" target="_blank">HERE</a>! </h2>
    <h2> To get your own DEADicated wristband, click <a href="http://store.cinderblock.com/the-deadicated-rubber-bracelet.html" target="_blank">HERE</a>! </h2>
    <h2> Can't get enough of Dead Sara?! <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Dead-Sara-Addiction-Treatment-facility/337823746314667?group_id=0" target="_blank">Dead Sara Addiction Treatment Facility</a> </h2>
    <h2> Email us at: TheDEADicated@TheDEADicated.org </h2>

</div> <!-- close main-content -->
```

And this is the CSS code for the main-content & headers:

```css
#main-content{
    padding: 50px 50px 30px 50px;
    background: #fff url('images/shadow.png') repeat-x;
    min-height: 800px;
}

#main-content h2{
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: url('images/ink-line.png') no-repeat left bottom;
    clear: both;
}
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you expect the website to actually look like.

Comment: We need more details - I see that you are probably floating each grey boxes, but show us the relevant styles that apply to elements in your example. Also, always try simplifying and illustrating your example with a Fiddle.

Comment: In the HTML, replace `<img src="images/sites/twitter.jpg"` with `<img src="<relative_path>images/sites/twitter.jpg"`. Also, ensure those images do exist

Comment: Sorry I thought that was in the post. The "To Join" is supposed to go together with "..The DEADicated..." right below the images and as you can see it's next to the Pinterest image. It shouldn't be there. And also there should be an image (ink-line.png) below each of the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct that you're not really clear about what you should see but don't, but if I interpret you correctly you mean that "my headings aren't showing the margin and padding or background images that I expect".

I'm going to take another leap of faith to offer up a possible solution. I see

```
</div> <!-- close main-content -->
```

at the end of your html but I don't see a `<div id="main-content>` anywhere. It should either be at the top of the page, or before the block of h2s, depending on what you desire the outcome to be. Try adding `<div id="main-content>` before the first h2 tag and see if that solves it for you.

**Edit:** I see your problem more clearly now, but this is tricky to resolve without the live url to inspect. It could be a float issue, but the clear should resolve that, unless it's being overridden, so you could change to:

`clear: both !important;`

It could be a display problem, so try adding:

`h2 { display: block !important; }`

If there's a live url that would certainly help. Final thought is to make sure every tag in the entire page html is properly opened and closed. Redundant or unclosed divs can cause issues like this in my experience.

Comment: I do have that <div> at the top. Sorry I wasn't clear, what I meant is that my first header "To join..." should appear below the last images and the (ink-line.png) is not showing below each one of the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what is happening here, but taking a guess at how the elements above the headers look, I'd say you have a float issue. Try removing the "clear: both" from the h2 and add "float: left; width: 100%;" in its place.

Comment: In that case, I'll join the chorus of others asking you to provide more details and code. I really can't solve a problem without know its parameters.